# Cannot set price or choose free trial for chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-platform, chrome-web-store

I’m developing a chrome extension and would like to make it a paid extension with a free trial. I uploaded my item onto the Developer dashboard and saved it as a draft, not submitting it yet. But on my Developer dashboard I don’t see an option to set the type of payment (free trial) or to set a price. Under Pricing & Distribution it says ‘Pricing and payment information can only be added in the old dashboard’ but there’s no option there either. My goal is to set a price and check if a user has paid when the trial has expired.

Steps I have taken:

- I have paid $5 in Google payments center and under Account in my
  Developer dashboard it says fee has been paid
- I added at the long key in my manifest.json, taken from the .pem I
  created by packing the extension (not using the crx in any way,
  just to get a key). I can upload a new item without any errors so
  the key seems to be working.
- On Google Cloud Platform I created a project with the exact same name
  and enabled the Chrome Web Store API. I generated a OAuth 2.0
  Client id - using my app name and 32 digit id generated by the
  developer dashboard - which I’ve added in my manifest.json

My manifest key and oauth2 now looks like:

```
"key": "MIIBIjANB…...",
 "oauth2": {
   "client_id": "19…...apps.googleusercontent.com",
   "scopes": [
     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chromewebstore.readonly"
   ]
 }
```

I added this in my background.ts:

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': true }, (token) => {
   console.log('token: ', token);
});
```

It already seems to be working showing me a Google window prompting to ‘Choose an account to continue to ’ and that my extension ‘wants to access your Google Account’ and can ‘View your Chrome Web Store apps and extensions’, and returning a token.

My questions are:

- Why don’t I see an option to select Free trial and set a price?
- In Google payments center I have two id’s, should my id here be the same as the first 12 digits of my client id by any chance (cos it isn’t)?
- Do I need to go through the process of creating an OAuth consent screen? In my project in Google Cloud Platform I now have that client id but it also says ‘To protect you and your users, your consent screen and application need to be verified by Google’ and creating the screen it requires ‘Authorized domains’, ‘Application Homepage link’ and  ‘Application Privacy Policy link’. Is this really necessary for an extension, which doesn’t have a homepage?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this feature has been disabled due to Covid-19.
"Chrome Web Store payments - We are disabling the ability to create new paid items or add payments to existing items. This includes extensions, themes, apps, and in-app purchases."
https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/r5EKL-McE3A/m/epeWeh-wAQAJ